# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting with Colors

Tags: conditional-formatting

I would like to setup a conditional format formula that applies to an entire column based on a legend. I have tried multiple custom formula's. However if I get it working for a single row when I drag the formula down it doesn't apply the custom conditional formatting formula to the others.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvnwgkavCWOPPsqGXIFwR6c4yvugdGvR0qvr37qw7-E/edit#gid=0

Here is a link to the sheet.

Comment: What is the conditional formatting formula you've tried?

Comment: Have tried using custom formulas for the rows like: =A2>150%*B2 , that didnt seem to work however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see anything wrong with your formula. When you set it up, you have the choice of highlighting the whole column from B2:B1000 then applying the rules, or getting them working on cell B2 only, then using the paint roller(or Edit | Copy then Edit | Paste Special | Paste Formats or Ctrl-C then Ctrl-Alt-V) to copy the formats into the remaining cells. I've suggested re-casting the formulas slightly so that they will error out when the stop value is missing so these rows aren't highlighted. You need to apply the rules from the most restrictive to the least restrictive. I've also added another category of within 100% of stop.

```
=A2/B2<=110%
```

etc.

Note that if you wanted the formulas to work in columns A and B say, you would need to put dollar signs in to fix the columns i.e.

```
=$A2/$B2<=110%
```

For column B only, it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Can't thank you enough Tom. I spent over 2 hours trying to figure this out. Much appreciated. Cant vote up your answer just yet, but will def come back and do so when I have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, appreciated.